# Google Sheets import Excel

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I have a formula that works well in excel, but when I import into Google Sheets, it doesn't work.

[image: https://prnt.sc/omniqb]

```
G3 =IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$14,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($C$2:$C$14)-ROW($C$2)+1)/($A$2:$A$14&$B$2:$B$14=G$2&$F4),1)),"")
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11wtlTjq_OqKzV6araDUKULlIs_Soi1lJ-5HF39JxF8c/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11wtlTjq_OqKzV6araDUKULlIs_Soi1lJ-5HF39JxF8c/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=QUERY(A2:C, "select B,sum(C) where C is not null group by B pivot A", 0)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: GREAT! Thank you my friend!